# How to write an .exe file using C# code with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, sockets, streamwriter

Actually I am copying an exe file over sockets. I am able to copy a text using `StreamWriter` Class but i used the same code for copying a exe file , it created a exe file with the desired name but I cannot run it.
"This app cannot run on your PC". I have Windows 8 x64, that is irrelevant.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
    tcpclient.Connect("localhost", 20209);
    NetworkStream stm = tcpclient.GetStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    var fs = File.Open("F:/aki/RMI/akshay.exe", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
    int x;
    while ((x=stm.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))>0)
    {
        **A**    streamWriter.Write(buffer);
        **B**  //streamWriter.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    }
    streamWriter.Close();
    fs.Close();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    //Console.ReadLine();
    tcpclient.Close();
}
```

I tried both A and B methods, B works for text file but not for an exe file. Any solutions?

Or I have to use any other Writer Class for exe files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a `Write(byte[], index, count)` method in the `StreamWriter` class to do that, but that doesn't exist. Calling `streamWriter(buffer)` is the same as `streamWriter(buffer.ToString())`, so that won't write the contents of the buffer, and using `Encoding.ASCII` to convert the binary content in the buffer to text will change it.

Don't use a `StreamWriter` at all. Write to the `FileStream` instead:

```
while ((x = stm.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
  fs.Write(buffer, 0, x);
}
```

You should use the variable `x` as the length to write rather than `buffer.Length`, as the buffer might not always be completely filled. At least the last block will almost never be a full buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A StreamWriter is a TextWriter. Can't you just do:

```
fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```